# Cannot create zip file in java using zip4j

Tags: java, eclipse, zip, zip4j

I am using java to create a zip file, but I cannot get any code to work.
I tried many more ways specific to java 7 and java 8, but all of them show some kind of error, is there a mistake in my code or it needs improvements?

```
            File destination = null;
            JFileChooser chooser1 = new JFileChooser();
            chooser1.setDialogTitle("Select a directory with APK file contents");
            chooser1.setCurrentDirectory(new java.io.File("."));
            chooser1.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);
            chooser1.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
            int returnVal = chooser1.showOpenDialog(getParent());
            if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                destination = chooser1.getSelectedFile();
                JFileChooser chooser2 = new JFileChooser();
                FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("APK Files", "apk");
                chooser2.setFileFilter(filter);
                chooser2.setDialogTitle("Save APK as");
                int userSelection = chooser2.showSaveDialog(parentFrame);
                if (userSelection == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                    File apksavedestination = chooser2.getSelectedFile();
                    String apkname = chooser2.getSelectedFile().getName() + ".apk";
                    String zipFile = apksavedestination + apkname;
                    String zipfileSource = destination.getAbsolutePath();

                    try {
                        ZipFile zipFileAtLast = new ZipFile(zipFile);
                        ArrayList<File> inFolder = new ArrayList<File>();
                        inFolder.add(new File(destination.getAbsolutePath()));
                        ZipParameters parameters = new ZipParameters();
                        parameters.setIncludeRootFolder(false);
                        parameters.setCompressionMethod(Zip4jConstants.COMP_DEFLATE);
                        parameters.setCompressionLevel(Zip4jConstants.DEFLATE_LEVEL_NORMAL);
                        zipFileAtLast.addFolder(inFolder, parameters);
                    } catch (ZipException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

I get an error at this line `zipFileAtLast.addFolder(inFolder, parameters);`

Please guide me :)

> Errors while runtime:
>
> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.Error: Unresolved
>   compilation problem:      The method addFolder(ArrayList,
>   ZipParameters) is undefined for the type ZipFile
>
> at dpcs.Interface$3.actionPerformed(Interface.java:143)     at
>   javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
>     at
>   javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
>     at
>   javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
>     at
>   javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
>     at
>   javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
>     at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6535)    at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)    at
>   java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6300)  at
>   java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)  at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4891)     at
>   java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)     at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)     at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
>     at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
>     at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
>     at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)    at
>   java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2750)   at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)     at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
>     at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)   at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)   at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)

Comment: What is the error that you get? Can you post a stack trace of the error?

Comment: Posted the errors that I get at runtime and Eclipse says to add cast to addFolder

Comment: You are trying to pass an `ArrayList` to the `addFolder()` method. Check the method signature in the [API](http://javadox.com/net.lingala.zip4j/zip4j/1.3.1/net/lingala/zip4j/core/ZipFile.html) for addFolder, it can either take a String (the path to the folder you want to zip), or a File object(pointing to the same folder). What are you trying to achieve here? Zip the contents of an entire directory? If yes, then you should use something like this `zipFile.addFolder(new File("/path/to/dir/which/you/want/to/zip"), parameters);`

Comment: Still not working, tried your methods @Chetan

Comment: What do you mean not working? Karan bhai please be more specific and try to post the actual exception/stack trace instead of generic "not working"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. The problem was, all the solutions required File object to be converted to string first!

Answer (score 1):

Hope these links helps

> [How to create a zip file in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091788/how-to-create-a-zip-file-in-java)
>
> https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/courses/629/jdkdocs/api/java.util.zip.ZipFile.html
>
> http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/java.util.zip.ZipFile
>
> [How to add a file in a specific folder (in the ZIP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22461428/how-to-add-a-file-in-a-specific-folder-in-the-zip)
>
> http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?class=net.lingala.zip4j.core.ZipFile&method=addFolder